# How can I find these partial derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm reading a book which gives this function $f(x,y)=x^2y/(x^2+y^2)$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$ as a $C^1$ function in $\mathbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$, continuous in $(0,0)$ and it has the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$. In fact the author wants to point out a function which has the partial derivatives in $(0,0)$, but it's not differentiable in $(0,0)$.

The problem is I can't find the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$ I think I should use the limits.

See:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{2xy(x^2+y^2)-2x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{x^2(x^2+y^2)-2x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

They aren't defined at $(0,0)$. How can I proceed to find these partial derivatives at $(0,0)$?

Thanks

Comment: It's much easier than that. What is $f(x,0)?$ What is $f(0,y)$?

Comment: @zhw. yes, indeed! thank you for the hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the partial derivative at $(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ is

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}$$

The analogous limit applicable to the partial derivative with respect to $y$ at $(x,y)$ is

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(x,y+k)-f(x,y)}{k}$$

Here, $x=0$ and $y=0$ while $f(0,0)=0$.  In addition, $f(h,0)=0$ and $f(0,k)=0$.  Thus

$$\left . \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{0,0}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{0-0}{h}=0$$

and

$$\left . \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{0,0}=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{0-0}{k}=0$$

So, both partial derivatives are $0$ at the origin.

It is interesting to remark that while the partial derivatives exist at the origin, the partial derivatives are not continuous there.

Comment: Thank you, it's easy, I should have tried this!

Comment: In order to show the non-continuity of the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ should I use limits?

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  You would have seen this eventually, but really glad I was able to help in any way.

Comment: You have found the partial derivatives for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and correctly noted that the limit of these partial derivatives as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ do not exist.  Thus, they cannot be continuous as the origin.

Comment: I proved this? I think I should prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\neq 0$ and $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\neq 0$, no?

Comment: @user42912 Yes absolutely.  Show that those limits are not $0$.  In fact, those limits might not even exist?